# Copying data between two remote hosts - how does it works?

Tags: linux, shell, aix

I need to copy data from host A to host C. There is no connection between them. Only way is A <-> B and then B <-> C.
To made this in some faster way I use the following command on B (the middle server):

```
    ania@hostname_B: /home/ania/
    ssh hostname_A 'cd /home/ania/lot_of_files; tar cf - .' | ssh hostname_B 'cd /home/ania/new_place; tar xf -'
```

It works, but I don't understand something here and really would like to. 
Where is hidden in this command is the strictly copying data?

I see normal ssh connection, change the directory and packing/unpacking files only done on two hostnames and after another separated by pipe.
No files after execution are stored on hostname_B, there is no scp here used also.
Done on AIX, but it will work on Linux also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo | bar` means "take all normal output from `foo` and pass it as input to `bar`" ("normal" since there is also "error" output).

It doesn't really matter what `foo` or `bar` are as long as the first one writes it output to `stdout` (a.k.a "file handle 1") and the second one can read from `stdin` (or file handle 0).

SSH does something similar but involving sockets. So it connects to the SSH server on a different computer (via [Unix Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)) and redirects `stdin/out/err` of the command running on the remote computer to the `stdin/out/err` of the `ssh` command which you executed locally.

So if you do `ssh user@host echo Hello`, then SSH will send the command `echo Hello` to the remote SSH server which will execute it "locally" (i.e. on the same computer where the SSH *server* is running). The result (`Hello`) will be piped through the SSH server into the socket connection to the computer running the `ssh` command which has set up its pipes to redirect the data to it's `stdout`.

So we have:

1. `tar` on `A` collecting data and piping that to the SSH server on `A`
2. The SSH server on `A` sends the output on to the first `ssh` command via Unix Sockets
3. The first ssh command pipes (or streams) everything to it's `stdout` where the `|` (pipe) command picks it up.
4. The pipe command passes the output of the first `ssh` to the second.
5. The second `ssh` sends the data to the SSH server on `B` via Unix Sockets
6. The remote SSH server on `B` pipes the data then to the second `tar` command as `stdin`

Or as a graphics:

```
tar cf --pipe>> SSH(A) --socket>> ssh hostA --pipe>> ssh hostB --socket>> SSH(b) --pipe>> tar xf
```

Where `--pipe>>` is a pipe between processes on the same computer and `--socket>>` is a Unix socket connection between two different computers.

Answer (score 1):

Well they are not seperated by the pipe, but joined with the pipe. Its basicly B connects to A and tars the files and streams the file to host C where it executes the tar xf so it unpacks the files.

Comment: Thank you Maximilian, you helped me.

Comment: No Problem - would you like to accept my answer if I answered your question? That would be nice.